# How to get json array from json object in SWIFT?

Tags: json, swift

Hello friends I need your help for reading the array from the `json object`.
like 
`{"info":[{"memoID":"3","memoName":"Hello"}]}`
using `SwiftyJSON`

when I'm in android I can use
`JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray(“info”);`

Comment: In Swift 4+ SwiftyJSON became obsolete. The `Codable` protocol is built-in (no dependencies!) and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

`JSONDecoder`

```
let content = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self , from: data)
print(content)
```

---

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct Root: Codable {
    let info: [Info]
}

// MARK: - Info
struct Info: Codable {
    let memoID, memoName: String
}
```

`SwiftyJson`

```
if let res = arr["info"].array { // arr is of type JSON
  print(res)
}
```

Comment: thanks but I want to use **SwiftyJSON** at sometime one class(ViewController.swift)

Comment: how you make the request `Alamofire` or what see edit